# How do I copy a file using ftp from machine A to machine B using command

Tags: linux, ftp, scp

I want to copy a file from source machine A to destination machine B, using command and want to use ftp.

I tried this

```
scp /home/varun/Desktop/Test.java username_for_target_machine@ip_address_of_target_machine:/home/Desktop/

The authenticity of host 'ip_address_of_target_machine (ip_address_of_target_machine)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 4a:49:cc:9d:ab:f6:ec:4f:b2:0b:63:ef:8f:b8:76:76.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ip_address_of_target_machine' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
qaserve@ip_address_of_target_machine's password:
```

When I give password for target machine

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I tried multiple time but I get the same output.

1. Where am I making a mistake?
2. How can I give a username and password in command so that it wont
   ask password?

**Update:1**

I tried using ssh. bellow are the steps what I followed.

**1. Verify that local-host and remote-host is running openSSH**

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

**2. Generate key-pair on the local-host using ssh-keygen**

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/jsmith/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
31:3a:5d:dc:bc:81:81:71:be:31:2b:11:b8:e8:39:a0 jsmith@local-host
```

**3. Install public key on the remote-host.**

```
[remote-host]$ vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa ABIwAAAQEAzRPh9rWfjZ1+7Q369zsBEa7wS1RxzWR jsmith@local-host
```

**4. Give appropriate permission to the .ssh directory on the remote-host.**

```
[remote-host]$ chmod 755 ~/.ssh
[remote-host]$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**5. Login from the local-host to remote-host using the SSH key authentication to verify whether it works properly.**

```
[local-host]$ ssh -l jsmith remote-host
```

When I run the above command I get:

```
ssh: connect to host remote-host port 22: Connection timed out
```

When I type

```
ssh -l ipaddress_of_remote-host remote-host
```

Its asking for a password : when I provide the password, it connects to the remote_host.

Why is it asking for a password again after I have registered the public key in the remote host?

**Update 2:**
 Sorry for mess.

1. I want to copy file from source to destination using any protocol.
   change the permission
2. [remote-host]$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   [remote-host]$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_key

Comment: The first line of your question says, "...want to use FTP." Why are you using SCP and SSH? These are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably don't have permission on /home/Desktop on remote server, you may want to try /home/username_for_target_machine/Desktop
2. No, I don't think so. But you can Google for "ssh Public Key Authentication"

Comment: Please see the updated question

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing various things here. First of all none of this has anything to do with ftp. You're using `scp`, not `ftp`. Why are you mentioning ftp? Then, you seem to be attempting to connect to the host using the IP as a username (`-l` gives the user name to connect as). Also, the permissions are wrong for the `authorized_keys` file, you need `600` and `700`, not `644` and `755`. Finally, that really isn't a good way to copy keys around anyway, that's what `ssh-copy-id` is for.

So, let's try from the beginning. Steps 1 and 2 are OK, now do this:

1. Remove the entry you added to the remote `authorized_keys` file.
2. Fix the permissions on the remote host:

   ```
   [remote-host]$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
   [remote-host]$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorised_keys
   ```
3. From the local host, copy your key to the remote:

   ```
   [local-host]$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@ipaddress_of_remote-host
   ```
4. Try logging in again

   ```
   [local-host]$ ssh jsmith@ipaddress_of_remote-host
   ```
5. It looks like the host is not exporting its name to the network correctly. For a quick fix, run:

   [local-host]$ echo "ipaddress_of_remote-host    hostname" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

   That will save the name of the host as an alias for its IP. Now, you should be able to connect with `ssh user@hostname`.

Comment: `1st step: remove the entry from authorized_keys.` `2nd step : change the permission to as you mentioned` `3rd step  [local-host ]$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub qaserver4@remotehost
ssh: connect to host remotehost port 22: Connection timed out
[local-host ]]$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub qaserver4@ipaddressof_remotehost'
qaserver4@ipaddressof_remotehost''s password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'qaserver4@ipaddressof_remotehost'", and check in:
  .ssh/authorized_keys`
`to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.`

Comment: when I tried 4th step  `ssh qaserver4@remote-host` dind work. tried ssh `qaserver4@ip_address_of_remote_machine`
its ask for password, when I provided the password. it got connected with target machine. But still its is asking for the password

Comment: @varun yes, it looks like you haven't set up the host to work with hostname. See updated answer, use the IP instead of the name and see step 5 for how to use the name in future.

Comment: I tried step 5 and i save ipaddress with my hostname.      When I tried this     `ssh qaserver4@qaserver4`
`The authenticity of host 'qaserver4 (ipaddress_of_target_machine)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 4a:49:cc:9d:ab:f6:ec:4f:b2:0b:63:ef:8f:b8:76:76.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'qaserver4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
qaserver4@qaserver4's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.`
`qaserver4@qaserver4's password: `
`Last login: Wed Oct  7 17:58:58 2015 from qaserver3` but it still asking for the password

Comment: @varun is the username the same as the server name? Why are you doing `ssh qaserver4@qaserver4`? Shouldn't that be `ssh varun@qaserver4`? Anyway, that error is because i) there is no `qaserver4` user on `qaserver` or ii) you are using the wrong password.

Comment: yes my user name is same as host name

Comment: When I do `ssh qaserver4@qaserver4` terminal prompt me for password . I provide the password and I get to connect with target machine. But still I have to provide the password.

Comment: @varun OK, please edit your question and add the output of `ssh -vvv qaserver4@qaserver4`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't configure your FTP as it is asking for password so just  check this link :

1) http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.2/html/opensuse-manual_en/manual/sec.filetrans.copy.html

**To configure an FTP server, proceed as follows:**

```
**Prepare the FTP server:**

    Install the vsftp package.

    Open a shell, login as root and save a backup copy of /etc/vsftpd.conf:

    cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.bak

    Create an access point for anonymous FTP

    mkdir ~ftp/incoming
    chown -R ftp:ftp ~ftp/incoming

Replace the configuration files depending on the scenario you prefer (refer to the manual page of vsftpd.conf for advanced configuration options):

Allowing Anonymous Read and Write Access

    #
    listen=YES

    # Enable anonymous access to FTP server
    anonymous_enable=YES

    #
    local_enable=YES
    # Enable write access
    write_enable=YES
    anon_upload_enable=YES
    anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
    dirmessage_enable=YES
    # Write log file 
    xferlog_enable=YES
    connect_from_port_20=YES
    chown_uploads=YES
    chown_username=ftp
    ftpd_banner=Welcome to FTP service.
    anon_root=/srv/ftp

Grant Restricted Permissions to FTP Users (Home Only)

    chroot_local_users=YES

Restart the FTP server:

rcvsftp start
```

On the client, just enter the URL ftp://HOST in your browser or FTP client. Replace HOST with either the hostname or the IP address of your server. There are many graphical user interfaces available that are suited to browse the contents of your FTP server. For a list of them, just enter FTP at the search prompt of the YaST package manager.

Comment: Please see the updated question